# running multiple test cases independently in a single test suite with out app relaunch

Tags: jestjs, detox

How can I run multiple test cases in a single test suite independent of the other without relaunching the application. I am currently using only single it() function.

```
it('', async function(){ ...menutestcase, ..homescreenTestcase, ..SettingsTestcase, ...});
```

I want to run all test case independently, that means, if one test fails, the other will be continued. Currently this feature can be achieved using multiple it() functions for each test case. like

```
it('', async function(){ ...menutestcase);
it('', async function(){ ...homescreenTestcase,);
```

but the problem is that, for every it() function call , the app relaunches for every it() function call and I have to login each time the app launches.

Please help if there is any way to fix this.

Comment: What about putting the login in an `beforeAll` block.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Is there any device farming services like AWS-farming for testing react-native application on multiple devices. Please help if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

gone through the reference
 https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/detox/test/e2e/f-device.js

I was using

```
// beforeEach(async () => await device.reloadReactNative());
```

Now, I commented it out and added device.reloadReactNative() only in the first test case. this way it worked.

```
// beforeEach(async () => await device.reloadReactNative());
it('', async function(){ 
         await device.reloadReactNative();
         ...menutestcase
  );
it('', async function(){ ...SettingsTestcase,);
it('', async function(){ ...homescreenTestcase,);
```